# Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Installed Nvidia CUDA 11
Got the cuDNN 8.0 (I think)
Added the directory to PATH
Installed TensorFlow through (pip install tensorflow-gpu)

But I still get this error

```
Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
```

Comment: I do not think the latest version of tensorflow supports CUDA 11. Believe you need to use CUDA Toolkit v 10.1.  This link provides instructions https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

Answer (score 0):

TF 2.4 supports CUDA 11
TF 2.3 needs CUDA 10.1

Just install CUDA 10.1 (you can have more than one instalation)